# Change color of this custom class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I am working with a cocoa pod library in my app. After installing it using `pod install` all I had to do was add this code to bring a iOS banner pop up. https://github.com/Loadex/MessageBanner

On the above link, there is a section which describes how to change the iOS banners attributes i.e. color, imagery, duration etc. When I look at the color section it's a little vague by only listing the hypothetical property name and possible values for the desired effect and not the code itself.

Can with pod expertise someone help me understand this cocoa pod library to change the banner color to one of its included hex values , i.e. blue?

```
[MBLMessageBanner showMessageBannerInViewController:self
                                              title:@"Welcome,"
                                           subtitle:@"User..."
                                              image:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"icon.png"]
                                               type:MBLMessageBannerTypeMessage
                                           duration:MBLMessageBannerDurationDefault
                             userDissmissedCallback:^(MBLMessageBannerView *bannerView) {
                                 return;
                             }
                                        buttonTitle:@""
                          userPressedButtonCallback:^(MBLMessageBannerView *banner) {
                              return;
                          }
                                         atPosition:MBLMessageBannerPositionTop
                               canBeDismissedByUser:YES delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the type to one of these 4?

> MBLMessageBannerTypeError: The error message banner.
>
> MBLMessageBannerTypeWarning: The warning message banner.
>
> MBLMessageBannerTypeMessage: The standart message banner.
>
> MBLMessageBannerTypeSuccess: The success message banner.

It has 4 default color schemes. If you want to edit or create your own, go to **MBLMessageBannerView.m** and apply your changes on  `(void)applyMessageStyleFromDictionnary:(NSDictionary *)messageStyle`